# Exclude versioned documents while Querying-Raven db

Tags: ravendb, database-versioning

I have appended the versioning  bundle in midway of my project after having written most of my raven queries in my data access layer. Now because of versioning i have lots of replicated data. Whenever i query a type of document i can see the values replicated as many times as the document is versioned. Is there way to stop querying the re-visioned documents when i query for the current data in common without re-writing all of my queries with **Exclude("Revisions")**.Is there any setting where i can say **query on re-visioned document =False**  which i can set globally? please suggest something to overcome this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the way it works, actually. It appears that you have disabled the versionning bundle, which would cause this to happen.

Comment: ya that works ayende.. Forgot to add the default configuration file. which caused the problem.